# IndexedDB undefined request

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm using IndexedDB for the first time and i'm still trying to figure it all out.
I (think I) added items in the IndexedDB on a page and on the next page i need to retrieve them.
Here's a portion of the code:

```
var db;
const dbName = "biometricData";
const osName = "userdata";

var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, 1); /*Creazione del database*/
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    db = this.result;   /*Salvo l'istanza del database al momento della crazione*/
    alert ("Database creato");
    updateBatteryData();
};
request.onerror = function(event) {
  var error = request.error;
  alert(error);
};
request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
  /*Chiave di ricerca e creazione dell'objectstore*/
  db = this.result;
  alert("Upgrade Needed");
            if(!db.objectStoreNames.contains(osName)) {
                alert("Devo creare l'Object Store "+osName);
                var objectStore = db.createObjectStore(osName, { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement:true });  
                objectStore.createIndex("student","student", {unique: false});
                objectStore.createIndex("type","type", {unique: false});
            }
};
```

This is to create the database at first

```
function updateBatteryData() {
        batteryData = {id:id,
                       student:matr,
                       type:6,
                       index:batteryDataIndex,
                       time:data["time"],
                       batteryLevel:data["batteryLevel"],
                       isCharging:data["isCharging"],
                       dischargingTime:data["dischargingTime"]};

    var transaction = db.transaction([osName], "readwrite");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(osName);
    var request = objectStore.add(batteryData);

    request.onsuccess = function(event)
    {
        alert("salvato il primo valore di batteria");
    }
}
```

Then i call this function to save the object in the DB (of course all of these values are not undefined).
Also, this is always id = 1.

Then, on the next page, i try to retrieve the data. I open the database at the same way i open it before and then i use this:

```
var transaction = db.transaction([osName]);
var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(osName);
var request = objectStore.get(1);
request.onerror = function(event) {
  alert("error");
};
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  alert("done");
  alert(event.target.result.type);
};
```

The thing is this: if i create the database for the first time, get the values, save them, then retrieve them on the next page it doesn't do anything, it says that the value is undefined. If I do the same thing for the second time with the database already created it actually finds the data.

What am I missing?

Comment: So to be clear - you run page1.html (or some such) which creates the db (possibly) and adds the value. You run page2.html which fetches the value and it fails. But if you reload it, it works. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @RaymondCamden not if I reload page2. If I reload page1 and then go to page2 I get the "first time page1" values and the last values.

Comment: Heh I honestly can't tell what you mean anymore. :) So page1 works, page2 doesn't work on first load but does on second?

Comment: Suppose that you compile a form on page1: you open page1 for the first time ever, compile the form and send data to the IDB. Then when finished you press a button that sends you to page2 where you retrieve all the information on the IDB. page2 on this case does nothing. If you open again page1, compile again the form and go to page2 again you find all the info about the first form and all the info about the second.

Comment: That sounds... weird. ;) So it is online where we can see?